# The question is about 问讯

Tags: phrase

(I am learning Buddhism/dharma in Chinese.)

为什么合掌鞠躬叫"问讯"？

或是说：

为什么现在的"问讯"不是用讲的？

"问"和"讯"都是动词吗？还是动词+名词？

Comment: bkrs:问讯 (3) [put the palms together (a Buddhist greeting)]∶僧尼跟人应酬时合十招呼。 也叫"打问讯"
for explanation search web: http://baike.baidu.com/view/116499.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

依[香光莊嚴](http://www.gaya.org.tw/magazine/v1/2005/59/art1.htm)解釋：
在漢語的構詞上，問訊是由「問」與「訊」二個同義詞所組成的詞彙。
「問」是動詞，意思是「恤問」。
「訊」是動詞，意思是「詢問」。

如果「訊」作名詞，在非佛教場合也還是可以用的。如：打聽消息。

現在的"問訊"也還是有用講的，但通常只在人少的時候。當很多人同時向佛或法師表達恭敬時，沒辦法大家都講，所以就只有身體的動作。

問訊 is composed of two synonyms, 問 and 訊.
Both are verbs, meaning "comfort and ask".

If 訊 is a noun, it can still be used in non-Buddhist cases.
Such as: to inquire about something.

Nowadays, 問訊 can still be used orally, but usually only in the cases of 2 or 3 people. When many people express respectful to the Buddha or the masters at the same time, they cannot speak all together. So they only show the body movements.

Comment: 建议重要的地方用英语标注，以免新手无法理解，谢谢。

Answer (score 0):

A word with multiple meaning.

汉典 ： [問訊](http://www.zdic.net/c/e/fc/265284.htm)

简单来说， 就是佛教借用这个词，用久了成规范。

同 `问好` 。 比如说： `遥遥点头问好` Greet with a node. 你不需要喊出来，不是吗？

如果是普通人， `問訊` 还是用说的或是写的。